# Getting the min() of a count(*) column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called Vehicle_Location containing the columns (and more):

```
ID               NUMBER(10)
SEQUENCE_NUMBER NUMBER(10) 
TIME            DATE
```

and I'm trying to get the min/max/avg number of records per day per id.

So far, I have

```
select id, to_char(time), count(*) as c
  from vehicle_location
 group by id, to_char(time), min having id = 16
```

which gives me:

```
ID                     TO_CHAR(TIME) COUNT(*)               
---------------------- ------------- ---------------------- 
16                     11-05-31      159                    
16                     11-05-23      127                             
16                     11-06-03      56
```

So I'd like to get the min/max/avg of the count(*) column.  I am using Oracle as my RDBMS.

Comment: Minor point, but using `TO_CHAR(TIME)` to get the day component relies on you having `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` set to something that doesn't include the time. The more common way to do this is with `TRUNC(TIME)`. And in this case I'd have put the filter on `id = 16` in the `where` clause, not the `having` clause, since it doesn't need to be evaluated after the grouping - either works but you might hit an index using `where`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have an oracle station to test on but you should be able to just wrap the aggregator around your `SELECT` as a subquery/derived table/inline view

So it would be (UNTESTED!!)

```
SELECT 
    AVG(s.c)
    , MIN(s.c)
    , MAX(s.c)
    , s.ID
FROM
    --Note this is just your query
    (select id, to_char(time), count(*) as c from vehicle_location group by id, to_char(time), min having id = 16) as s
GROUP BY s.ID
```

Here's some reading on it:
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Oracle/Inserting-SubQueries-in-SELECT-Statements-in-Oracle/3/

**EDIT:** Though normally it is a *bad* idea to select *both* the `MIN` and `MAX` in a single query.

**EDIT2:** The min/max issue is related to how some RDBMS (including oracle) handle aggregations on indexed columns. It may not affect this particular query but the premise is that it's easy to use the index to find either the `MIN` *or* the `MAX` but not both at the same time because any index may not be used effectively. 
Here's some reading on it:
http://momendba.blogspot.com/2008/07/min-and-max-functions-in-single-query.html

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to select both MIN and MAX in a single query?

Comment: I said *usually* because of how some RDBMS (including Oracle) plan `MIN` and `MAX` queries. It can quickly get either one, but when you ask for both it may not know which index to use. I have edited my answer.