# How to select only records that have minimum number of occurrence in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

Simplify sample of my database is a table which as

```
        CN REG#         CAPACITY
---------- ---------- ----------
         0 LUCY02          43000
         6 QRT834           5550
         3 SYF777           3333
        12 PKR768           1234
         5 SST005          12000
         6 KKK007          10000
         3 PKR008          22000
```

This has been created from joining two tables. Here is join statement:

```
select count(tp.reg#) as cn,t.reg#,  CAPACITY
from truck t
join trip tp 
on  t.reg# = tp.reg#
group by tp.reg#,  CAPACITY, t.reg#
```

Now, how can I write a statement to print only the lines which, has the minimum number of occurrence and nonzero. In our example it is 3.

Expected output is

```
     3 SYF777           3333
     3 PKR008          22000
```

What I have done so far but is not working is:

```
select count(tp.reg#) as cn,t.reg#,  CAPACITY
from truck t
left join trip tp 
on  t.reg# = tp.reg#
left join
(                       
    select dd, min(d) as ds
    from(
        select count(*)as d, ti.CAPACITY, ti.reg# as dd
        from truck ti, trip tp 
        where tp.reg# = ti.reg#
        group by ti.reg#, ti.CAPACITY
    )
    group by dd
)
on t.reg# = dd
group by tp.reg#,  CAPACITY, t.reg#
```

Comment: Something similar here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6259530/1854461 - does that work in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you could try this,

```
 select * from 
       (select count(tp.reg#) as cn,t.reg#,  CAPACITY
       from truck t
       join trip tp 
       on  t.reg# = tp.reg#
       group by tp.reg#,  CAPACITY, t.reg#)
  where cn = (select min(cn) from (select count(tp.reg#) as cn,t.reg#,  CAPACITY
                                      from truck t
                                      join trip tp 
                                      on  t.reg# = tp.reg#
                                      where cn > 0
                                      group by tp.reg#,  CAPACITY, t.reg#))
```

I hope is usful for you...
Thanks

Comment: This solution is independent of the value of min(cn), it works for this particular value (in this case 3) and for the value that min(cn) could have.

Comment: If you know, that min(cn) is always 3 you could use HAVING COUNT(CN) > 3. But I think it is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to filter your query based on an aggregate function like "count", simply add this filter in "having" statement:

```
select count(tp.reg#) as cn,t.reg#,  CAPACITY
from truck t
join trip tp 
on  t.reg# = tp.reg#
group by tp.reg#,  CAPACITY, t.reg#
having count(tp.reg#) >= 3
```

and if you want query records with minimum occurrence dynamically, you can use the code below:

```
select count(tp.reg#) as cn,t.reg#,  CAPACITY
from truck t
join trip tp 
on  t.reg# = tp.reg#
group by tp.reg#,  CAPACITY, t.reg#
having count(tp.reg#) = (select distinct top 1 count(tp.reg#) cn
                         from truck t
                         join trip tp 
                         on  t.reg# = tp.reg#
                         group by tp.reg#,  CAPACITY, t.reg#
                         having count(tp.reg#) >0
                         order by cn)
```

Comment: I think you assume that the minimun value that is not zero, is always three.

Comment: Bernard asked a way to return rows with minimum 3 occurrence. So you can change the number "3" in the code above with any desired number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wanted to filter it by variable minimum variable. If I add one more record with cn=2 it won't work.. As I said it is 3 in above example. Merc

Comment: thanks for your comment. I add some extra lines to my code for your situation. I think it is more optimized than "Alexis Sánchez Tello"'s code.

Comment: Yes, I think that your code, with the dynamic feature, is more simply and clear with the use of having.

Answer (score 0):

you just need couple conversions to the dynamic views and add filtering midway:

```
    select min(y.cn) , y.REG#, y.CAPACITY
from 
(
    select x.CN, x.REG#, x.CAPACITY 
    FROM 
    (
        select count(tp.reg#) as cn,t.reg#,  CAPACITY
        from truck t
        join trip tp 
        on  t.reg# = tp.reg#
        group by tp.reg#,  CAPACITY, t.reg#
    ) X
    WHERE x.cn != 0
) y
group by y.REG#, y.CAPACITY
```

.